# Oracle APEX ORA-01722 when creating Interactive Report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, plsqldeveloper, oracle-apex-20.2, oracle-apex-20.1

I keep getting an ORA-01722 whenever I try to save the page. This happens when I try to:

- Create a region as an Interactive Report: Tried 3 different tables, from the autmatic creation to typing the sql myself; With 1 or all columns; even doing a select 1 colX from dual;
- Change any classic report to interactive report and click save.
- If I create the interactive report from the template wizard, change to classic and try to move back, same issue.
- I've already tried only varchar columns, disables all features from the IR, gave it static id and basically turned everything off and on again.

Comment: Already happened to me, i had a letter or a comma in a number attribute like "column span" or something like that. So check all your item and region attributtes, and try to find which attribute is filled in wrongly.

Comment: Hi Valerio,That is exactly what I thought, but I created an environment where there is only the interactive report region and it has 1 column with the user name. There is nothing else, not page items, no other regions, nothing.... I still get the same message :(

Comment: Did you try to set debug ON and check what its results say? Also, if possible, create an example on apex.oracle.com and provide developer's credentials so that we could have a look.

Comment: Is this just happening on one page, in one application, in one workspace?  Have you tried creating a brand new page and add just one interactive region?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the questions, we've found the answer and posted it below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of jun/20 the issue is on chromium. I had to use firefox and noticed it wasn't happening, tried on chrome and opera and it was also ok.

Comment: Thanks for posting the work-around.  Feel free to accept your own answer; that helps both others with a similar problems, and folks looking for unsolved questions, to find (or ignore) questions with accepted answers.

Comment: Thanks Mark, it is accepted now.... I usually wait a few days to see if someone can find a better solution but this one slipped through my mind.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue but with Chrome. It worked for me to change to Firefox. It did however not help to dissable all chrome extensions.

Thanky you Paulo for posting solution.

Answer (score 0):

When I add the second IR, it is set by default in the section Printing -> BorderWidth = .5, I changed the value to = ,5 and it can be saved without the ORA-01722 error.